# How to change the Color of a text Passage in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I'm writing a Text comparing tool and would like to show the charaters who are not same in Red.
Thatfor I have to change the Color (with `setForeground()`?) of a Passage of the Text.
How can I do that?

Comment: how comes a JTable into that scenario?

Comment: Becouse I'me using a JTable to show the 2 files (don't ask why... I have to change that in a next step^^)

Comment: thanks - just curious: a cell contains what exactly?

Comment: it contains one line of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "< html>Some text< font color...>some text< /font>< /html>" for the cell's text.

Comment: So it works. the only problem that i had, ist that i used a JTextFrame into the cells and I have to use a JLabel. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of labels you will need to use a JEditorPane as your rendering component.

Look here for inspiration:
[How to insert JEditorPane into JTable cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147339/how-to-insert-jeditorpane-into-jtable-cell)